# How to determine if a directory is a valid git directory without requiring git?

Tags: git

There are a lot of questions in stackoverflow that ask about how to determine if
a directory is under git control. And the answer is using `git` command by calling
command via child process.

What I want to know is how we can determine if a directory is a valid git
directory?

`git init` command creates these files under `.git` directory:

```
config
description
HEAD
hooks
info
objects
refs
```

The same goes with `git init --bare`.

Let say I run `git init` command and then have `git` removed/uninstalled from
my system. And then I want to check if a dir is a `git` dir. Obviously, I can't
use `git rev-parse` command. So, I suspect the check need to be done by checking those files. In those files what are need to be exists there so the `.git` dir
is a valid `.git` repository? And is there any additional check need to be done?

**UPDATE** details:

What I need by valid here is the minimum checking to allow any other operations
further. I'm not good at explaining. But, let say I have two function (pseudo code):

```
fn is_valid(gitdir) {
    // here will happens checking if a git dir is valid. it doesn't care
    // if any content is corrupted.
    return valid;
}

fn current_branch(gitdir) {
    // here will show current branch. but, will only run if the gitdir
    // is valid
    // this function will read 'refs' directory
    return current;
}

fn list_branches(gitdir) {
    // here will list of branches. but, will only run if the gitdir is valid
    // this function will read 'refs/heads'
    return branches;
}
```

If I only check `.git` directory, it won't work on `bare` repository. Then, I
found that `git rev-parse` will only work if `HEAD`, `refs` and `objects` are
exist. So, if checking `HEAD`, `refs` and `objects` is sufficient?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "valid".

Comment: Define "valid". Is it OK if some Git objects are corrupt? What if *all* Git objects are corrupt? How much do you wish to allow to be "wrong" with the directory before you declare it invalid?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to be exhausive.

If you want to know if the current directory is a `.git` directory or something completly different, just check for the main folders existence (info, objects, refs).

If you to know if git will know how to work with it, meaning it's not just zeroed files, then you would have to develop a git file parser... it would then be easier to just use git.

Answer (score 0):

I think the existence of .git directory is a decent check to start with.
You could look at parsing the information in config and description, these are ASCII text files, if you needed some form of repo validation.

```
.git>$ ls -l | grep -v ^d | grep -v total | awk '{print "file " $9}' | sh
COMMIT_EDITMSG: ASCII English text
COMMIT_EDITMSG~: ASCII English text
config: ASCII text
description: ASCII English text
FETCH_HEAD: ASCII text
gitk.cache: ASCII text, with very long lines
HEAD: ASCII text
index: data
ORIG_HEAD: ASCII text
packed-refs: ASCII text
```

If you want to know if a given directory is in a git repo, then you'll build a directory tree and go up the tree until you encounter the existence of a .git directory.